# A faster/elegant way to replace some elements of a array from another array at the same index under conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, for-loop

I'm trying to replace for-loop with Numpy functions to speed up my program. The function below makes the territory of each label grows(background label=0).

The label territory don't erode others. So I create a double for-loops to check if some label are replaced with another label. If so, roll back to the original map.

However, these for-loops are making the process slow.

Python supports syntax like this: array1[condition] = x .
I'm wondering if x can be the value of array2 at the same index of array1?

Or is there some NumPy functions will do the job?

```
nb_components, mask, sizes, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=8)

nb_components-=1; sizes=sizes[1:,-1]; centroids=centroids[1:,:]
new = np.zeros((mask.shape))
for i in range(10):
    new = ndimage.maximum_filter(mask, 3)

    for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mask.shape[1]):
            if (mask[i][j]>0) and (new[i][j]>0) and (mask[i][j]!=new[i][j]):
                new[i][j]=mask[i][j]

    mask=np.copy(new)

#imshow(skimage.color.label2rgb(new, bg_label=0))           
#plt.show() 
return new
```

edit
My bad English might lead to misunderstanding. 
Here's a example. 
if the index is an odd number , replace a[index] with b[index]

a:(1,6,5,4,3)
b:(2,7,9,9,6)

so 6,4 are replaced with 7,9

Can I achiive this kind of thing in python without a for loop?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example with your input and the expected output. Also, this might be a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking this part of your question "I'm wondering if x can be the value of array2 at the same index of array1?"

In numpy there is Integer Array Indexing [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html].

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([4 ,0 ,5 ,3 ,2 ,2 ,0 ])
b=np.array([5, 17, 29, 38, 45, 52 ])

b[a]
Out[9]: array([45,  5, 52, 38, 29, 29,  5])
```

Does this help?

Comment: My bad English is leading to misunderstanding. I'll make an example

Comment: Your example is to change a if the index is even. You want 'np.where(a%2, a, b)'.  If a%2 is 1 (a is odd) use a else use b

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Thank you!